# convert txt to md, changing unix enf-of-line to double space

Tags: converters

I'd like convert a txt file (with many, many lines) in a md file, keeping the txt's end-of-line (double space in md file).
I need convert (txt) end-of-line to (md) double space.
I tried with **pandoc** but I get a file without desired end-of-line. So also many online services.
Thank you

Comment: Tried with awk:  awk '{ gsub("\n","  "); print>ARGV[1] }' lavati.txt  but not working (i'd like modify "lavati.txt")

Answer (score 0):

- Open the txt file in Kate
- find and replace as regex: find "\n" replace "  \n"
- it worked for me!